# php contact form 409 errors

Tags: php, error-handling, contact-form-7

The website I made for my client is https://pariswashcompany.com/
On this website I get error 409 when the contact form is submitted

I purchased the contact form from bootstrapmade.com Which is a professional company and In their instructions, they say "Fully functional contact form Just change the email to yours in contact.php and it works after that".
When I submit the contact form it throws me error 409 but my hosting company HostGator Cannot seem to solve it, so I was wondering if anyone else had run into this problem.

Solutions I have tried

1, Hostgator cleared website cache

2, we contacted the creator of the PHP contact form they said error 409 has to do with the hosting company (creator bootstrap made)

3, we contacted Hostgator and they told us to set our PHP to 7.4 within our cpanel

Comment: *"they told us to set our PHP to 7.4 within our cpanel"* Have you done it?

Comment: yes and it did not work

Comment: seems like working : https://prnt.sc/ZHzLK5Tyr5QA  and https://prnt.sc/1m5rPqfdXprt

Answer (score 0):

There are duplicate ids in the form.  **email** and **number** have the same id.  Ids should be unique.

```html
<form action="/forms/contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
   <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
   <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
   <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phone" id="email" placeholder="Your number" required>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group mt-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group mt-3">
  <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
</div>
<div class="my-3">
 <div class="loading">Loading</div>
 <div class="error-message"></div>
 <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
</div>
<div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
</form>
```

409 is about consistency/conflict

> The HTTP 409 Conflict response status code indicates a request conflict with the current state of the target resource.
>
> Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a PUT request. For example, you may get a 409 response when uploading a file that is older than the existing one on the server, resulting in a version control conflict.

Reference : [Mozilla : 409 Conflict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/status/409)

> 409 CODE REFERENCES
>
> Rails HTTP Status Symbol :conflict
>
> Go HTTP Status Constant http.StatusConflict
>
> Symfony HTTP Status Constant Response::HTTP_CONFLICT
>
> Python2 HTTP Status Constant httplib.CONFLICT
>
> Python3+ HTTP Status Constant http.client.CONFLICT
>
> Python3.5+ HTTP Status Constant http.HTTPStatus.CONFLICT

Reference : [What Is a 409 Status Code?](https://www.webfx.com/web-development/glossary/http-status-codes/what-is-a-409-status-code/)

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks for all your comments i appretiate it hostgator fixed this by white listing my websites code originally the code was black listed by the hosting company

hostgators response
Thank you for waiting. We successfully whitelist your contact
form in a mod sec and it seems fixed it. Can you try again now?

It appears there's a script or code in the contact form that was blocked in mod security.
No worries, it has been whitelisted permanently.